# Responsive Android Design (Not by Stretching or "MultipleX Layouts")

Tags: android, mobile, responsive-design, viewport

Additional note, I've added an image below to give you a better idea of the change I'm suggesting which I need comment on. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1biJL.jpg

Just to note, my question is is not about creating many fixed aspect ratios for different devices. Because IMO, eventually a device will be produced that will have weird aspect ratios. So no, I'm interested in advice on how to design with **a portion of the screen stretched** or somewhat similar ideas.

I've developed simple android apps before but I'm looking for a **game specific solution** to filling a screen, without stretching the whole graphics. *this is different from the proposed duplicate about creating multiple layouts [Android Responsive design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790466/android-responsive-design)*

So far I've tried:

- Stretching : renders out of proportion on wrong aspect ratios.
- Extend Viewport : ugly black bars on side of screen.

I have a vague idea that I need to declare a portion of the screen that will be stretched, for example 'the sky', or 'bottom menu'. So for example if I'm doing a platformer:

```
Vector bottomLeft = 0,0;
Vector topRight = DeviceScreenGraphics.getTopRight();
camera.setViewport(bottomLeft, topRight);
renderBackground(...);
renderForeground(...);
*renderScore(DeviceScreenGraphics.width/2 - currentScore.x/2, topRight.y - currentScore.inverseY);*
renderHero(...);
renderBottomBar(...);
```

However, I hit a bump when I have to render a popup into the middle of the screen? ++ seems like I need to add more relative positioning, this is troublesome especially when catching tap positions. ++

```
Vector diffFromTopRight = topRight - MyFixedAspectRatio.getTopRight();
renderPopup(popup.x + diffFromTopRight.x/2, innerTopRight + diffFromTopRight.y/2);
```

Am I heading in the right direction, if anyone has experience and could please guide me on such ideas? Should most of my "top floating elements" such as score be rendered to (Graphics.middle - Score.width/2,Graphics.top - Score.inverseY)? And popups ?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: What is your goal here? You ask “am I heading in the right direction” and say “any suggestions would be greatly appreciated”. The proposed duplicate suggests no, you are not heading in the right direction and proposes several solutions. Then you edit your question to say you're “looking for a better solution”. Why is your proposal for “a portion of the screen stretched” better than what the Android design guidelines say to do?

Comment: simply that I'm looking for a new solution... pertaining to games?(yes maybe i should have mentioned that). Humbly, I believe the android guidelines are generic -- games may have a slightly different structure..
and sorry if I wasn't clear on labelling my edit. I had stated that I'm "looking for a better solution" at the start. Let me edit that "looking for a game specific solution"