# Support different type of the screen programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

How can my layout support different screen without using the constraintLayout and using folders like layout-small, layout-large, layout-normal, and layout-xlarge. I dont want to use them since I do have plenty of layout. Please help me.
This is one of my layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/job_order_no"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text ="A"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developers/building-a-responsive-ui-in-android-7dc7e4efcbb3

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Responsive design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790466/android-responsive-design)

Comment: I cant create another layout file since it is very time consuming and I have a dozen of layouts. Do you have another alternative solution? Like using programmatically set the height and width? using LayoutParams perhaps?

Comment: Software development is generally time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Try Using LinearLayout with weightSum and weights. 
Below is example which divides 2 Buttons equally on screen,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can change weightSum and weights as per your requirement.
Just make sure sum of all weights must be equal to weightSum.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to create 2 folders in res directory such as values-sw600dp(compatible with 8 inch tab) and values-sw720dp(compatible with 10 inch tab).
In values-sw600dp,create dimen.xml and specify dimension in that file according to your requirement.(for 8 inch tab).
In values-sw720dp,create dimen.xml and specify dimension in that file according to your requirement.(for 10 inch tab)

for example:

```
    <dimen name="txt_title">20sp</dimen>  (in values-sw600dp)
    <dimen name="txt_title">24sp</dimen>  (in values-sw720dp)
```

and use it above dimen in your layout as follow:

```
    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_title"
```

You can also set height and width of views using this.

Hope this will help you.